# Usin AWS IoT to offer a service to thirdy party

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I would like to leverage AWS IoT to offer a service to my customers. Customers can be both "thing" owners or data consumers. The added value is given by computational stuff on the platform. Is such a scenario possible? I would like to implement a REST API to let users register their own things and maintain the association with Customers and things, but I don't want the thing to require my Amazon credentials in order to push data. Is such a scenario possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could issue individual certificates for each of your customers. AWS IOT already supports this.

AWS can generate the certificates for you or you could generate and sign your own certificates. You'll probably prefer to issue your own certificates since allows you to fine control your customers accesses, this feature is also supported by AWS Iot. To generate and sign your certificates you could use tools such as openSSL.

AWS IoT already supports REST API out of the box

Last step is how you'll charge your customers. You can create a rule that will copy all messages to a lambada function that will work as an aggregator and count how much messages each of your customers sent. This last step is a little bit tricky since you'll have to know the device names of your customers.